# Is Safari's "Close Tabs to the Right" a new feature released in macOS 10.15.4?

Tags: macos, safari, catalina, tabs

After updating to macOS Catalina 10.15.4, I've noticed a new `Close Tabs to the Right` option when right clicking a Safari tab:

[image: tab options]

I'm not 100% sure if this came with the 10.15.4 update thought, since [the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_4_release_notes#overview) don't actually say anything about this. When did this feature first appear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's new in Safari 13.1, even on Mojave.

Safari 13.1 will run on macOS High Sierra, Mojave, and Catalina (specifically versions 10.13.6, 10.14.6, and 10.15.4), It's the Safari version that's key, not the OS version itself.

Here's the changelog which show this: [Safari 13.1 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_13_1_beta_release_notes)

> - Added Close Tabs to the Right.
> - Added Duplicate Tab.